# Is it possible to vertically align an image with text when the image is inserted as content in a pseudo element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align an image within a psuedo (before) element and some text beside it. I've tried adding

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

To both the image & the text. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this? Also negative vertical margins aren't affecting the pseudo element.

Css:

```
.email {
    &:before {content: url('../images/envelope.png');}
}
.phone-number {
    &:before {content: url('../images/phone.png');}
}
.about-me {
    &:before {content: url('../images/avatar.png');}
}
```

Markup:

```
    <ul>
        <li><h3>Jon Doe</h3></li>
        <li><a href=""><p class="icon phone-number">250-555-5555 ext. 2</p></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><p class="icon email">email@email.com</p></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><p class="icon about-me">About Me</p></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: vertical-align doesn't do what you think it does. vertical aligning in CSS has always been a miserably painful experience because the idiots at the W3C have never ever look at a real web page in their lives.

Answer (score 2):

With your current markup, you definitely can't use vertical-align.  I've modified the markup shown below using a div around the text.  Depending on the size of your icon images, you can use padding to vertically align the text next to each icon image -- assuming that all of the icons are the same height.

Alternatively, you can use an icon set like FontAwesome -- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ -- and all icons will be loaded on the page faster than images and all of them will be guaranteed to be the same height.  That way, when you set the padding on the top and bottom of the text, you can ensure that it's leveled vertically in the middle of each icon.

```css
p.email:before {
  content: url('../images/envelope.png');
}
p.phone-number:before {
  content: url('../images/phone.png');
  float: left;
}
p.about-me:before {
  content: url('../images/avatar.png');
}
div.text {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
li {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Jon Doe</h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <p class="icon phone-number">
        <div class="text">250-555-5555 ext. 2</div>
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <p class="icon email">
        <div class="text">email@email.com</div>
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <p class="icon about-me">
        <div class="text">About Me</div>
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? I could have read it wrong...

HTML

```
<ul>
            <li><h3>Jon Doe</h3></li>
            <li><a href=""><p class="icon phone-number">250-555-5555 ext. 2</p></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><p class="icon email">email@email.com</p></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><p class="icon about-me">About Me</p></a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      left: -5px;
      background-color: black;
}

.email {
    &:before {
      background-image: url('https://secure-a.vimeocdn.com/images_v6/portraits/portrait_50_blue.png');
    }
}
.phone-number {
    &:before {
      background-image: url('https://www.placehold.it/20x20/241');
    }
}
.about-me {
    &:before {
      background-image: url('https://www.placehold.it/20x20/331');
    }
}
```